# Need help in understanding "for any vector $a \in [n]^2$..." where $[n] = \{0, 1, ... n-1\}$

Tags: algorithms, notation

In a paper I see "for any vector $a \in [n]^2$..." where $[n] = \{0, 1, ... n-1\}$
What can it potentially mean? $[n]$ seem to be a set.... what then $[n]^2$ might denote? Especially we say for any vector $a$.

Any guesses?

P.S paper is [HERE](http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~agupta/_projects/naid/revsketch-tech.pdf) 
(page 8, middle left column) ...

Comment: It might mean the Cartesian product.

Comment: @HenryW actually that would make sense I guess, THANKS